Functor $F\circ G$ with Natural Transformation to $1$ (Identity Functor)
This is a very broad question...but I'm looking for properties regarding a given map$^{1}$ $G:C\to D$ (where $C,D$ denotes categories) such that $F\circ G$ has a natural transformation to the identity functor $1:C\to C$ for some functor $F:D\to C$.
For further context, I am trying to understand how Wikipedia (link - Definition via Universal Covering) made the following claim:

In this situation, one can show that $G$ can be turned into a functor $G:C→D$ in a unique way such that $\epsilon_{X}∘F(G(f))=f∘ϵ_{X'}$ for all morphisms
$f:X′→X$ in $C;$ $F$ is then called a left adjoint to $G$.

(See image below for context to the above statement from the Wikipedia article.)

More specifically, why can we conclude $G$ defines a functor? Upon drawing out the diagram, all that I can see is that the commutativity condition (i.e. $\epsilon_{X}∘F(G(f))=f∘ϵ_{X'}$) tells us that $F\circ G$ denotes a functor with natural transformation to identity.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

$^1G$ is specifically denoted as being a map here since I'm trying to prove that this map $G$ denotes a functor on the $C\to D$, as seen with the Wikipedia quote.

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why.

I don't understand the first part of your question, but if you're looking for a proof of the Wikipedia claim then see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor#InTermsOfRepresentableFunctors

@NaïmFavier Edited the original post. Hopefully I'm a little more clear now. (And having glanced at the NCatLab link you provided, this does clarify a lot about the Wikipedia article, though I still remain curious on properties regarding the maps as described in the original post.)

The conclusion that $G$ is a functor is nontrivial, but the linked nlab page contains a proof. $F \circ G$ is only a functor because $G$ is, so I still don't understand your question.

@NaïmFavier I guess I'm just looking for general properties with the question at the very top of my original post. Though I think the main question of this post (pertaining to the Wikipedia article) is good now.
